# Show the following relation related to densities

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $X$ be a set and define the upper and lower uniform densities as follow: $$M(X) = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{|X \cap[x,x+r]|}{r},$$ and $$m(X) = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{|X \cap[x,x+r]|}{r}.$$ If $X \subset d \mathbb{Z}$ show that $M(X)+m(d\mathbb{Z} \setminus X) = 1/d$. What I can show is that $M(d\mathbb{Z}) = m(d\mathbb{Z})= 1/d$ without too much trouble. But I cannot seem to find a way to get the desired result. Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: $$lim\left(max_{x\in R}\left(\dfrac{|X\bigcap[x,x+r]|}{r}\right)\right)+lim\left(min_{x\in R}\left(\dfrac{|X^{c}\bigcap[x,x+r]|}{r}\right)\right)=lim\left(max_{x\in R}\left(\dfrac{|X\bigcap[x,x+r]|}{r}\right)+min\left(\dfrac{|X^{c}\bigcap[x,x+r]|}{r}\right)\right)$$ 
$$=lim\left(\dfrac{|X\bigcap[x',x'+r]|}{r}+\dfrac{|X^{c}\bigcap[x',x'+r]|}{r}\right)=lim\left(\dfrac{|dZ\bigcap[x',x'+r]|}{r}\right)$$
(not the whole proof just the general direction, you need to show that the maximum and the minimum are obtained for the same x)

Comment: @BinyaminR: How exactly can one show that this is true though? I see how this justifies the relation, but how does one go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some playing around I think this should do it. Suppose that the $$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |X \cap [x,x+r]| = |X \cap [x',x'+r]|,$$ for some $x' \in \mathbb{R}$. Fix $r \in \mathbb{N}$, then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$|X^c \cap[x,x+r]| = |d\mathbb{Z} \cap[x,x+r]| - |X \cap[x,x+r]| \geq |d\mathbb{Z} \cap[x,x+r]| - |X \cap[x',x'+r]|.$$ Take the minimum over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ of this inequality and we get $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|X^c \cap [x,x+r]| + |X \cap [x',x'+r]| \geq \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |d\mathbb{Z} \cap [x,x+r]|.$$ Dividing both sides by $r$ and taking the limit as $r \rightarrow \infty$ gives us $$m(X^c) + M(X) \geq m(d\mathbb{Z}) = \frac{1}{d}.$$ We can get the other inequality by arguing similarly. Hence $M(X) + m(X^c) = 1/d$.